# Plot values from different variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find the solution for my problem.
I have  some points I want to plot and each of this points correspond to one variable. My question is: How can I plot each point in the same plot with unique color each and plot a legend.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

function=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
acc_scores = [0.879, 0.748, 0.984, 0.944, 0.940]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors= ['b', 'r', 'g', 'c', 'y'] #Colors I wanted to use for each data point
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5], acc_scores, 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0.5, 1])
ax.set_xlabel('Functions', size=18)
ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy', size=18)
plt.show()
```

This code gives me the points, but all the same color.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is even an [example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) on the matplotlib page about this.

Answer (score 0):

You're plotting all of your data as one line plot, and they're all the same color because you specified `ro`. If you want each point to be different, you can loop over each point and plot it individually. The `label` parameter is helpful for building a legend.

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

function=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
acc_scores = [0.879, 0.748, 0.984, 0.944, 0.940]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors= ['b', 'r', 'g', 'c', 'y'] #Colors I wanted to use for each data point
for x, y, c, f in zip([1,2,3,4,5], acc_scores, colors, function):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, label=f)

plt.axis([0, 6, 0.5, 1])
ax.set_xlabel('Functions', size=18)
ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy', size=18)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: Example Output]